# React and Express running on different localhost ports but CORS NOT blocking the fetch call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, cors

I am trying to understand why doesn't CORS block the Axios get call. Details are as follows:

```
React running on:    localhost:3000
Express running on:  localhost:3001
```

Express code:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.get('/test', ((req, res) =>{
  return res.json({data: "hello world"})
} ));

app.listen(5000, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost: 5000`)
})
```

React Front End Code macking the call:

```
function App() {

   useEffect(() => {
      //______________________ CALL ___________
      
     axios.get('http://localhost:5000/test').then(res => console.log(res.data))

     // Able to see the data returned by the server in the console

   })

  return (
    <div className="App">
        <h1> TESTING REQUEST </h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: CORS security does not block (all) requests; it blocks the client from seeing the response content.

Answer (score -1):

Here it will not restrict because both the request are going to localhost(which is same origin). Basically the origin of end point from where the react is being served is same as the express.
`An example of a cross-origin request: the front-end JavaScript code served from https://domain-a.com uses XMLHttpRequest to make a request for https://domain-b.com/data.json.` 
check here for more details https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Answer (score -1):

if you want to make it work.
you can explicitly enable CORS like this

```
const cors = require('cors')
app.use(cors()) // this will Enable All CORS Requests
```

you can configure your hosts on to of this by passing config object like this

```
var corsOptions = {
origin: 'http://example.com',
}


 app.get('/products/:id', cors(corsOptions), function (req, res, next) {
  res.json({msg: 'This is CORS-enabled for only example.com.'})
})
```

for more details
https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html